# Is React-Native a single threaded execution or multi-threading execution?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to know whether React-Native supports single threading or multi threading approach with example

Comment: A close-related one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130319/multi-threading-in-react-native

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's single threaded. Please refer this link. I think it will clear all your doubts.
https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/parallel-multithreading--workers

Comment: When I click the link, I get, "There is no such post."

Answer (score 8):

Javascript is single threaded. Since React Native is essentially JavaScript (+ native UI), it is single threaded out of the box.

You can however start a new JS process (usually to carry out CPU intensive tasks) using [react-native-threads](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads) which essentially is a different thread. You can go through the library docs if you want to know more about how it works.