# how to call API using thread in React native using redux?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, react-redux, react-router

how to call background thread in react native.creating an application using background thread to call API. Suggest me to achieve this.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { WebView } from 'react-native'

    export default class BackgroundTaskRunner extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <WebView
            ref={el => this.webView = el}
            source={{html: '<html><body></body></html>'}}
            onMessage={this.handleMessage}
          />
        )
      }
      runJSInBackground (code) {
        this.webView.injectJavaScript(code)
      }
      handleMessage = (e) => {
        const message = e.nativeEvent.data
        console.log('message from webview:', message)
      }
    }
```

This is way to call background Thread or is there any better way to perform API call using thread ?

Comment: Please share code that you've tried

Comment: react-native doesnt support multi threading, so i believe best way is to use redux and dispatch an action

Comment: okay I have not tried it so please give an idea with code-snippent will be helpful

Comment: You should try it first with your own hypothesis about this problem, try your hypothesis first to test your knowledge, if all your effort didn't make any move then posting for help. You can only be improved when learning that way.

Comment: Btw, ReactNative app using JS to implement so there is no multi-threading in ReactNative. You have to learn about asynchronous in JS, utilize redux, redux-saga to handle your app state, call API and store into state. Incase you want to achieve the benefit of multi-processing, try to write native libraries by Swift (iOS), Java (Android) and then integrate it into your application

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is not supported in React-native. So to call an api you can either use redux which dispatches an action which in turns calls an Api via axios. So either by redux methodology or you can use simple [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library for it.

I would suggest you to use axios since it will be neat , you can simply do this by :

```
import axios from './axiosWrapper';

export const getItineryRequest = async tripId => {
  const params = {
    packageId: '26169',
    packageId: tripId,
    ip: 'true',
  };
  return await axios.get('app/user-package-details/', {params});
};
```

Where `axios.get` is a get request. Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you. can you give an example of using redux and not using anythird party library for this task

Comment: axios is one of the most used library and its trusted, and if you want to use redux , that also requires 3rd party and . in the end axios

Answer (score 0):

There is [react-native-threads](https://github.com/joltup/react-native-threads) which is the closest to multi-threading available right now. See [why Javascript doesn't support multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550055/is-react-native-a-single-threaded-execution-or-multi-threading-execution).

What you are trying to achieve is actually pretty common and achieved by the common libraries, Javascript executes code concurrently instead of parallel which won't make a distinction unless you are doing CPU heavy stuff.

Here's a snippet that will work out of the box in React Native. Note `fetch` here is a global variable. The [React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network) is a great place to get started.

```js
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
  return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.movies;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is just API call but not using any thread in background.